# Google Play In-app billing for unsupported countries

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play

I'm working on an app that's suppose to have in-app billing. We have 6 modules in app - one will be free and the other 5 can be purchased.

From what I've gathered, I need a Google Wallet Merchant account for that and unfortunately, I live in one of the unsupported countries. Can I just create a bank account in other country and use it for my Google Wallet Merchant account ?

Comment: I got a notification today saying they've added new countries. Check again. Maybe you'll get lucky.